# Tempo da função clock em valor inteiro ao invés de float

Tags: c++

Estou criando uma micro engine, por motivo de estudo, e queria simular um vetor de movimento de um corpo/objeto através do tempo.

Comecei fazendo um loop infinito para fazer as atualizações do vetor do objeto ao passar do tempo, mas logo tive problema com o tempo: estou usando a biblioteca ctime, com a função clock(), salvando o clock inicial fora do loop, num tipo clock_t. Depois pego novos clocks, subtraio, e divido pelo macro CLOCKS_PER_SEC.

O problema que essa divisão sempre me mostra resultado inteiro, e não real (float). Na verdade, quando mando imprimir, e forço um dos elementos da divisão como float, o resultado sai como float, mas na aplicação do programa isso não acontece.

O código abaixo imprime: 0 0 0 0 ... 1 1 1 1 ... 2 2 2 ...

```
    clock_t t1 = clock();
    clock_t t2;
        
    
    while (1) {
    
        t2 = ( clock() - t1 ) / (float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        cout << t2 << endl;
    }
```

Já esse imprime: 0.001   0.002 ... 0.542   0.543 ... 1.147... da forma como eu queria usar os valores, mas isso só acontece com a impressão. Na atribuição ele salva o valor inteiro.

```
clock_t t1 = clock();
   clock_t t2;
       
   while (1) {
   
       cout << ( clock() - t1 ) / (float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
   }
```

Como ligo com esse problema? Está havendo algum erro de minha parte?

Estou usando a IDE Dev C++ com o compilador GCC

Comment: Você pode declarar `t2` como `float`: `float t2;`

Comment: Nossa, obg! Funcionou! 

Eu tinha tentando fazer isso com o t1, n sei pq, só assim que funcionou!

Comment: Sabe me dizer pq isso acontece?

Comment: `clock_t` pode ser tanto `float` quanto `int`, então precisa definir o tipo que você quer. Tem respostas mais detalhadas no SO se você quiser saber a fundo.